# When is memory allocated in the .NET compact framework?

Tags: .net, memory, compact-framework

When is memory allocated in the .NET compact framework? If there is a difference between value and reference types, please detail. Documentation or steps to confirm are appreciated.

In particular, consider this scenario...

```
private MyClass item;  // here?

public void MyMethod()
{
    item = new MyClass();  // or here?
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 3 different ways memory is allocated.

**Static:**

These are bound and allocated at compile time. Global static variables for example.

**Stack Dynamic:**

These are bound during runtime and pushed onto the stack. Such as a local variable in a function call.

**Heap Dynamic:**

Now heap dynamic also has a few different 'sub categories' such as implicit and explicit, but I won't go into that detail.

When you declare

```
private MyClass item;  // here?
```

a reference to MyClass is pushed onto the stack. It is only a reference and nothing more. Its value is null at that point.

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    item = new MyClass();  // or here?
}
```

It is at that point where memory is explicitly allocated on the heap by calling 'new MyClass()' and item then references it.

So in actuality, you have 2 variables after you call MyMethod. A refernce type named item, and an unnamed variable on the heap which item references that is of type MyClass.

Answer (score 1):

This is something of a trick question, which makes me like it a lot more than I thought I would. :)

Let's start with the basics:

Declaring a variable does not directly allocate memory* for it on reference types. It **does** do so on value types, because value types are initialized at the point of declaration. For reference types, storage for the object is allocated at the point of entering their constructors.

*When does this not apply?

- On the first usage of a given class (which may well be your first line), any class-level static data is initialized, and if the class has a static constructor (which presumably allocates memory), it will be called as well. Therefore, you may actually allocate some memory (for the static members) at a variable declaration.
- Technically, declaring your reference type variable **does** allocate some memory, on the stack (as Nicholas Mancuso mentioned) -- the memory allocated is the stack-level storage for the reference to the object. (Admittedly, said reference is `null`, but once you initialize your object, a valid reference will exist in the allocated memory.)

I highly recommend this [C-Sharp Corner article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/csharp_memory01122006130034PM/csharp_memory.aspx?ArticleID=9adb0e3c-b3f6-40b5-98b5-413b6d348b91) regarding stack and heap allocation for more information.

Comment: Very nice answer, adds a few things Nicholas left implied. I'll up vote, but he's getting the answer points. Thanks!

Comment: And he ought to; his answer was more thorough. :) He and I answered at almost the same time, off by just a minute or so. :)

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend that you look at the MSDN Webcase on [Compact Framework Memory Management](https://msevents.microsoft.com/cui/WebCastRegistrationConfirmation.aspx?culture=en-US&RegistrationID=1299365950&Validate=false).  It's not exactly the same as how it works on the desktop, and this talk covers it with a whole lot of detail and graphics to aid in understanding the GC Heap.

Comment: The link is <https://msevents.microsoft.com/cui/WebCastRegistrationConfirmation.aspx?RegistrationID=1299365950>

Comment: But the event is over and I can't find an upload of the video or presentation.

Comment: Just register and it will give you a download link.  It's not very intuitive.